# Convert cct and cs2cs scripts to pyproj

Tags: pyproj

I am working on a RTK application where I use proj7.1 to make necessary transformations. The application is written in python3.7 using subprocess.Popen to call cct and cs2cs which may have performance impact as the software is running on Raspberry PI 3B hardware. I have tried to use the pyproj instead but so for no luck. Maybe someone can give me a pointer how this could be done using my scripts shown below.

I have two scripts first I convert from ITRF2014 epoch 2020.4 to ETRF97(1999.5)

pipeline2 = (
"echo %f %f %f |cct -t 2020.4 -c2,1,3 +ellps=GRS80 +proj=pipeline "
"+step +proj=cart "
"+step +init=NKG:ITRF2014 +inv "
"+step +init=NKG:SE "
"+step +proj=cart +ellps=GRS80 "
)

After that I transform to SWEREF99TM+RH2000 with this command

"echo %f %f %f | cs2cs  +init=epsg:7928 +to +init=epsg:5845 +geoidgrids=SWEN17_RH2000.gtx "

Best regards Assar W.

Comment: You might try `Transformer.from_pipeline`: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/api/transformer.html#pyproj.transformer.Transformer.from_pipeline

Comment: Thanks. I have tried to make a pyproj pipeline as pipe_str=(
     "+ellps=GRS80 +proj=pipeline "
     "+step +proj=cart "
     "+step +init=NKG:ITRF2014 +inv "
     "+step +init=NKG:SE "
     "+step +proj=cart +ellps=GRS80 "
 )  pipe_trans = Transformer.from_pipeline(pipe_str) When I call it test=pipe_trans.transform(18,64,100,errcheck=True) I get "File "pyproj/_transformer.pyx", line 487, in pyproj._transformer._Transformer._transform
pyproj.exceptions.ProjError: transform error: point not within available datum shift grids" BTW How do I add -t 2020.4 and -c2,1,3 to the pipeline?

Comment: Does this help: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/examples.html#d-transformations-with-time ?

Comment: Thanks, tt=2020.4 was missing from the call so now it works.